# Can not get current location Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using [GeoLocator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Geolocator) in my Xamarin forms application also implemented [Permissions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions/4.0.1-beta) Plugin. But on android `locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));` It shows exception `A geolocation error occurred: Unauthorized`

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location.gps", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location.network", Required = false)]
```

**Info.plist**

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location access is required to serve you better</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location access is required to serve you better</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Location access is required to serve you better</string>
```

Comment: Which platform? Have you declared the permission in the application manifest?

Comment: Both iOS and Android, Yes I have added Permissions in manifest file as well as info.plist file.

Comment: Check the source code of the plugin, what could be the issue. For example on Android, are you setting the `CrossCurrentActivity` in `MainActivity`? - https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/blob/c18a061b712cad82f14c980e13301a199c3f8012/src/Geolocator.Plugin/Android/GeolocatorImplementation.android.cs#L117 .

Comment: yes its already added  `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;` in MainActivity.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually trying to solve the same problem today and may have found a solution.

First of all, make sure you install both **Permissions** and **Location** plugin into all your projects (including the .NET Standard shared project and platform projects).

Also, I was using the latest beta version, but that seemed to be causing issues and threw the `Unauthorized` exception even though a direct check resulted in `Granted`. After installing the **stable version** (4.5.0.6), it started working as expected.

Comment: Great, happy coding!